# Offline OpenLayers web app using offline OSM

Tags: asp.net, openlayers, openstreetmap, offlineapps

I'm trying to create map based web app which user can set landmark on the provided map. Boundaries of map is limited to a small city, and the client computer is always offline, no internet access at all. After a whole day of googling I've found that combination of [OpenLayers](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3) and [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) is a good choice.

The following example is provided by **OpenLayers** website:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([37.41, 8.82], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works fine, but needs an internet connected computer. 
After couple of hours of googling, I found another [website](http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html) that provides offline **OpenStreetMap** data with `.osm` format. 
Now I don't know is it possible to feed the OpenLayers with these `.osm` files or not, something like a local map server? the client computer is running **IIS 8**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For displaying a map offline with OpenLayers (or Leaflet) you will need raster [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles). A `.osm` file cannot get displayed directly because it contains raw vector data and has to be rendered first.

For generating tiles take a look at [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) or [TileMill](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TileMill). Then import a [country or area extract](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Extract#Country_and_area_extracts). Alternatively you could [set up your own rendering server](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/) which requires a little more work.

Comment: is there any tutorial to run a rendering server?

Comment: Yes, the tutorial is behind the link in my answer.

Comment: Does TileMill provide a url to feed OpenLayers? I have installed it and created a new project using offline data, but I don't know how it works!

Comment: As far as I know you have to export the map using the MBTiles file format. MBTiles in turn can then get extracted using [mbutil](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) which yields a directory structure usable for OpenLayers and Leaflet.

Comment: I used [Maperitive](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Maperitive) and [mb-util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) to create `{x}/{y}/{z}` directory structure. And with OSM [tutorial](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Local_Tiles_Example) it shows offline tiles. Keep in mind, because it uses `file:///` protocol you need to run the page on an `http` server.